# What is the coordinate value after moving counterclockwise by distance $d$ from a coordinate on the ellipse?

Tags: matrices, circles, conic-sections, rotations

Let me define an ellipse function as follows: Assuming $a \ge b$,
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} = 1,$$
where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the origin of the ellipse, and $a$ and $b$ are the maximum length of the radius on the major and minor axes, respectively.

Then, starting from a point $\mathbf{x} :=(x,y)$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(x,y) = 1$, I want to find $\mathbf{x'} := (x', y')$ such that

- $f(\mathbf{x'}) = f(x',y') = 1$ and
- The length of the arc of the ellipse from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}'$ is a specific given vale $C$, i.e., $d(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'}) = C$, where $d(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'})$ represents the length of the arc of the ellipse from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}'$.

---

If $a = b$, I can get $\mathbf{x'}$ easily using the rotation matrix, i.e.,
$$
\mathbf{x'} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\left(\frac{d}{a}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{d}{a}\right) \\ \sin\left(\frac{d}{a}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{d}{a}\right) \end{bmatrix}\left(\mathbf{x}-\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}\right) + \begin{bmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Is there any method to get the point after having movement by length $d$ from a point, when $a \ne b$?

Comment: The arc length of an ellipse involves an "elliptic integral," which cannot be solved in closed form, so anything you do will have to involve numeric approximation of the integral.

Comment: @kccu Ah.... That news makes me frustrated.... but thanks for your comments.